# Change default run command of VSC Docker extension

Tags: node.js, docker, visual-studio-code

When right-clicking on an image in Microsoft's Docker plugin and selecting `run` it executes the following command:

`docker run --rm -d  -p 3000:3000/tcp falaen:latest`

I would like it to run the following command instead:

`docker run --restart=always -v /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock:/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock -p 3000:3000 -d falaen`

I have tried to modify the run command in the Dockerfile but without success.
Of course, I can run the command manually in the terminal each time but it would be nicer to simply right click on the image and then run it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try adding this line to your VSCode's `settings.json`, to override the default configuration of the command.

```
"docker.commands.run": "docker run --restart=always -v /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock:/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock -p 3000:3000 -d ${tag}"
```

This will run the command using any image you select.